# Running complex query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

My goal is to do two things:
-Count the number of `votes` (this table is called `votes`) for each `songID` in a particular room.
-Find out if the userID has at least one vote for a song(in a particular room)

The `userID` and `RoomID` are passed into the queries.  I am not sure how to 'loop' through each `songID`.  Do I run two queries - first get each `songID` and then run a `for` loop to get the above information (using Java for this)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SongID, count(*) as voteCount, 
case when exists( 
        select 1 from votes b 
        where b.songID = a.songId and b.RoomID = ? and b.UserID = ? ) 
    then 'Yes' else 'No' end case as didUserVote
from votes a
where a.RoomID = ?
group by SongID
```

If that doesn't work, try this - the third column will be null if the user didn't vote for the song, and `UserID` if they did.

```
select a.SongID, count(*) as voteCount, b.UserID
from votes a left join votes b on a.songID = b.songID and b.RoomID = ? and b.UserID = ?
where a.RoomID = ?
group by a.SongID, b.UserID
```

Comment: OK, I checked the MySQL documentation, and this should work.  But I'm not going to go to the trouble of installing MySQL just to try it out for you.  Try dropping "as didUserVote" to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: OK, now I'm confused.  You've just accepted this answer; at the same time as posting a comment saying that there's an error.  Does it work or not?

Comment: well i got the original version working somewhat but it wasn't outputting 'no'...but the null version works for me! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do this for the first question

```
SELECT Count(songID), songID
FROM votes
WHERE RoomID = @roomid
GROUP BY songID
```

And this one for the second question

```
SELECT songID
FROM votes
WHERE UserID = @userid
      AND RoomID = @roomid
```

Comment: thanks, looks like i was missing the 'group by' feautre....any idea how i can combine both queries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in third coulmn if retunr is NULL there is no vote

```
select SongID, count(*) as voteCount,(
        select b.userid from votes b 
        where b.songID = a.songId and b.RoomID = 131 and b.UserID = 70)
    from votes a
    where a.RoomID = 131
    group by SongID
```